# Minimum size of a Diophantine equation detecting the emptiness of a recursive set

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

I have a program $P$ taking an integer as input and outputting a Boolean value. It runs in polynomial time in the length of the input.

There necessarily exists a Diophantine equation that has a solution iff the program assumes "true" on some input. Can the minimum size (in bits) of such a Diophantine equation be bounded in terms of the size of the program?

Comment: Yes, it’s at most linear in the size of the program. Consider a fixed Diophantine predicate $P(x)$ that expresses “the program with code $x$ assumes ‘true’ on some input”, and substitute the code of your program for $x$.

Comment: Yes, the algorithm converting recursive functions to Diophantine equations is explicit and boundable, eg as in Martin Davis’s American Mathematical Monthly article on Hilbert’s 10th problem. I have voted to close this as not a research-level question.